# Can I move from a tunnel to any tunnel?

Tags: scythe

About mine movement: can I move from a mine where I am to any other mine in the map? or only to the closest one?

Comment: The title of the question is misleading, since the real question is about mines. Maybe it should be reformulated.

Answer (score 10):

There are two different things in Scythe which are related here, Mines and Tunnels.

Mines are buildings you can build, they look like this:

[image: Mine wooden icon]

And here's how they work, from [the rulebook](https://app.box.com/s/rj3jrw0rab2uiz02up89kbant5g8ew1p/file/49368403634):

> The Mine acts as a
> tunnel **that only you can use**.
> You may move units to and
> from your Mine as if it is a
> tunnel (even if an opponent
> controls the territory the
> Mine is on). Unlike the other
> structures, this is an ongoing
> ability associated with all
> unit movement.

And then there are Tunnels, they look like this on the map:

[image: Scythe board with tunnels]

And here's what [the rulebook](https://app.box.com/s/rj3jrw0rab2uiz02up89kbant5g8ew1p/file/49368403634) says about them:

> For the purposes of the Move action for any unit, all
> territories with the tunnel icon are considered to be
> adjacent to each other.

So, in short, you can move:

- From a tunnel to any tunnel
- From a tunnel to *your* mine
- From *your* mine to any tunnel

You cannot use mines built by your opponents for your movement in any way.